# iOS -Is Write Denied Error In Firebase Security Rules Or In The Rules Simulator?

Tags: json, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

My Database structure is:

```
root
  |
  @-users
  |   |
  |   @-uid
  |      |
  |      @-registration
  |      |     |
  |      |     |-completed: true
  |      |
  |      @-sneakersPath//registered users post/write sneaker for sale to this path
  |            |
  |            |
  |            @-autoID//i.e. xyz123
  |                |-sneakercondition: "used"
  |                |-sneakername: "nike"
  |
  |
  @searchSnkPath//registered and anonymous users can search/read the sneakers for sale here
      |
      @-autoID//xyz123
          |-sneakercondition: "used"
          |-sneakername: "nike"
```

I'm developing an iOS app only logged in users can use and I'm using Firebase as my backend. I'm using 2 of the Firebase Sign-In Methods: Email/Password and Anonymous. I have a login scene with a email/password field and a button to enter in as an anonymous user.

There are 2 scenarios:

1. A user creates an account using the `Email/Password` method. They have to fill out email and password fields. Once they do that this user gets a permanent uid and a `registration path` is created. At that registration path I add a key/value pair of `completed:true`. From that point on the user presses a login in button to enter the app (they're logged in with their permanent uid). This user can post`(write)` sneakers for sale to a `sneakersPath`. They can also search`(read)` for sneakers that they or other users posted for sale.
2. An anonymous user uses the app without creating an account using the `Anonymous` method which is an anonymous button. They press the anonymous entry button and they can enter the app. Once they press that button they get a temporary uid that is unique to their visit (they're logged in with a temporary uid). Since this user is anonymous the only thing this user can do is search`(read)` what other users from the 1st scenario posted for sale. Once they logout if they log back in anonymously they get a different temporary uid.

In both situations I run checks on the `client side` to verify if a user is logged in as registered user or if they are an anonymously user. Based on those checks I can prevent an anonymous user from posting sneakers anonymously. Everything is working properly.

Even though I run the checks on the iOS side I want to had some extra enforcement in my Firebase Rules to make sure an anonymous user can't post anything and I want to run a check on the kvp `completed:true` specifically:

```
root.child('users').child($uid).child('registration').child('completed').val() === true"
```

Right now my security rules are:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "users": {
       "$uid": {
            ".read": "$uid === auth.uid && auth != null"
            ".write": "$uid === auth.uid && auth != null && root.child('users').child($uid).child('registration').child('completed').val() === true"   
   }   
  }
 }
}
```

**When I go to the Firebase Rules Simulator and try to write I get:**

[image]

[image]

In the below picture I have Authenticated switched to the right to "on" and the only choices I got were Anonymous, Google, Facebook, Twitter, and Custom. Since I'm using Email/Password and it's not listed I chose Custom. I also don't have the Admin box checked because I don't know what it is for.

[image]

Am I doing something wrong in my Json Security Rules or am I using the Rules Simulator incorrectly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that inside the Firebase Database I had to add the same exact foo uid data that Firebase had given me inside the simulator.

```
root
  |
  @-users
  |   |
  |   @-uid//this is another user's uid
  |   |  |
  |   |  @-registration
  |   |  |     |
  |   |  |     |-completed: true
  |   |  |
  |   |  @-sneakersPath
  |   |        |
  |   |        |
  |   |        @-autoID
  |   |            |-sneakercondition: "used"
  |   |            |-sneakername: "nike"
  |   |
  |   |
  |   @59c96197-7cf9-44d3-bfbc-8d4f3324461//this is the foo uid the simulator provided. It must be added in the db so it can read it
  |   |  |
  |   |  @-registration
  |   |  |     |
  |   |  |     |-completed: true
  |   |  |
  |   |  @-sneakersPath
  |   |        |
  |   |        |
  |   |        @-autoID//abc789
  |   |            |-sneakercondition: "new"
  |   |            |-sneakername: "reebok"
  |
  @searchSnkPath
      |
      @-autoID//xyz123
      |    |-sneakercondition: "used"
      |    |-sneakername: "nike"
      |
      |
      |
      @-autoID//abc789
          |-sneakercondition: "new"
          |-sneakername: "reebok"
```

Here is the foo path/uid data that the simulator provided:

[image]

Note the foo uid is also inside the token payload:

[image]

**If your going to use real data that's inside your database to test in the simulator make sure you delete the foo path/uid the simulator provides and replace it with whatever path/uid is in your database or you'll keep getting a Simulated Write Denied response.**

Inside the token payload you can keep the `"provider" : "anonymous"` to use with your the real data from your database but be sure to replace the foo uid with whichever one your using